# Type de métonymie : la composition pour la nature

Tags: figure-de-style

J’entends souvent, surtout dans le langage mercatique, une description amorcée par le verbe être (« Telle chose *est* […] ») de sorte que l’on s’attende à la révélation de la nature, en fait de laquelle est énumérée la composition.
Le cas typique se retrouve, comme je le disais, dans le nauséabond style publicitaire comme par exemple « L’entreprise X c’est surtout 500 personnes qui travaillent, des machines, des locaux […] ».

J’ai en horreur une telle façon de parler mais cette figure de style porte-t-elle un joli nom ? En tout cas, j’y ai vu une assimilation à la métonymie ; qu'en penser ?

Answer (score 2):

Il me semble que dans votre phrase (« X, c'est 500 personnes, des machines, etc. »), il n'y a pas de figure de style mais une simple définition du terme de départ.
La figure métonymique qui est « le tout pour la partie ou la partie pour le tout » s'appelle la synecdoque. La formulation d'une telle figure pourrait être « les cinq cents têtes qui travaillent pour vous », « la grande machine (= l'entreprise) qui vous propulsera vers l'avenir », etc.

Comment: Justement, ce n’est pas une synecdoque puisque nous avons là « le tout pour… l’ensemble des parties » ou, plus exactement « L’énumération de l’ensemble des parties en fait de définition ».

Answer (score 1):

Loin d'être savant, je n'arrive pas à trouver une réponse parmi les propositions offertes pour [métonymie](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9tonymie).

Comme il ne s'agit que de valoriser une **définition** du concept visé, je dirais simplement qu'il s'agit, selon le Robert, de :

> **vantardise**, de *vanter* : « Parler *très favorablement* de quelqu'un ou de quelque chose, en *louant publiquement et avec
>   excès*. »,

... ce qui est très désagréable aux oreilles honnêtes.

Sinon on peut faire comprendre son irritation en qualifiant la tournure de :

- Expression à la mode,
- Jargon mercantile,
- Dialecte publicitaire,
- Pub'argot ou argot de com'

---

**EDIT** *après commentaire*

*(« Telle chose est […] »)* est le paradigme de la définition.
L'absence de logique, de réalité, de véracité d'une définition est le fait des rhéteurs dont Schopenhauer donne les méthodes dans *[L'art d'avoir toujours raison](http://www.philo5.com/Mes%20lectures/Schopenhauer,%20L%27art%20d%27avoir%20toujours%20raison.htm)* (et les conséquences en sous-titre) *et de se faire détester de tous*.

On pourrait conclure en affirmant que :

> La rhétorique mercantile devient de plus en plus insupportable.

Comment: Certes mais il n’en reste pas moins que c’est une construction de phrase particulière. Il s’agit de la forme que je cherches à qualifier et non le fond (qui très certainement relève du registre mélioratif et même franchement mercantile).

Comment: @Fauve J'ai complété ma réponse pour prendre en compte vos remarques.

Comment: Certes mais les constructions *non sequitur* elles mêmes connaissent plusieurs sous-types :) Aussi, je ne suis pas satisfait de ce que j’ai pu trouver. Et pour cause, je crois que cette notion ne porte pas de nom. Une néologie s’impose.

Comment: @Fauve A mon sens il ne s'agit pas d'une *construction* logique avec `si ... alors ...`, mais d'une *définition oblitérée, incomplète, dithyrambique* même si elle utilise les principes de la rhétorique : "voilà ce que c'est ... et je ne vous dit pas tout, je me focalise sur ce point ... je valorise ces qualités essentielles à mes yeux ...". Ce serait plus de la morale (péché d'orgueil, mensonge par omission, vanité) que de la linguistique, ce qui justifierait le 'manque' que vous soulignez.

Comment: Certes mais certaines ruptures syntaxiques sont justement des figures de style :) La chose dont on parles est très certainement ce que l’on appelle un solécisme mais il reste encore à catégoriser plus précisément ce solécisme.
Certes, il semblerait qu’il n’ai pas de nom et c’est pour ça que je recourt à la néologie :)